# How to solve the following set of equations (magnetohydrodynamics with anomaly term)?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, quantum-anomalies, magnetohydrodynamics

Let's have system of equations:
$$
\tag 1 [\nabla \times \mathbf E^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t) ] = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t)}{\partial t} ,
$$
$$
\tag 2 [\nabla \times \mathbf B^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t)] = \sigma \mathbf E^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t) + A\left(\mu^{(1)}_{5}(\mathbf r , t) \mathbf B^{(0)}(\mathbf r , t)  + \mu_{5}^{(0)} \mathbf B^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t) \right),
$$
$$
\tag 3 \frac{\partial \mu_{5}^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t)}{\partial t} = D (\mathbf B^{(0)}(\mathbf r , t) \cdot \mathbf E^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t)).
$$
Here $A, C, D, \sigma , k$ are constant numbers, $\mathbf B_{0}$ is known and is equal to $B_{0}g(t)(\sin(k_{0}z), \cos(k_{0}z), 0)$, $g(t)$ is slowly varying function (so I have neglected $\mathbf E^{(0)}$).

If we can neglect term $\mu \mathbf B^{(0)}$ in $(2)$ and when $[\nabla \times \mathbf B^{(1)}] = k\mathbf B^{(1)} , k << k_{0}$, the solution is known. But what to do with system $(1)-(3)$ in general case? Can it be solved analytically, is there some exact solution exist? May method of separation of variables work here?

The system has arisen from the Maxwell equations which have been modified by the chiral anomaly term.

Comment: In general, the MHD equations (like the Euler hydrodynamics & Navier-Stokes equations) must be solved numerically. Also, what are the (0) and (1) superscripts denoting?

Comment: @KyleKanos : I have expanded general set of equations on series of some small parameter $\epsilon$. For example,
$$
\mathbf B (\mathbf r , t) = \mathbf B^{(0)}(\mathbf r , t) + \epsilon \mathbf B^{(1)}(\mathbf r , t) + ...
$$